# Rails: No route matches error for requests forwarded through Kong (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, kong

I have a Kong instance setup on Heroku, that forwards requests (matched by path) to an API service I developed and hosted also on Heroku.

When trying to access the route through kong, I receive 404 code, although when I try to access it through the service directly I get 200 code with the response body.

After checking the heroku logs of my service, the only difference I can find is in the `fwd`, other than that the requests are identical, yet yield different responses.

I have tried with my other services, also Rails apps, and also deployed on Heroku under other subdomains and it works fine with them.

Request forwarded through Kong:

```
2019-08-29T14:02:55.855196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/v2/my_path" host=subdomain.domain.com request_id=ff74f402-9369-49c6-bdc3-c5743b888684 fwd="77.9.33.254, 10.33.32.50,54.153.223.157" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=834 protocol=https
```

Request direct to service:

```
2019-08-29T14:04:56.874156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/v2/my_path" host=subdomain.domain.com request_id=120527af-0885-4a45-9350-24e747bead6d fwd="77.9.33.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=173ms status=200 bytes=1807 protocol=https
```

I expect to receive the same response from Kong as the one from coming directly from the service.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue comes from the fact that we use a subdomain constraint in our API routes, and since Kong uses `X-Forwarded-Host` header which has the value of the Kong instance domain name, it does not match the subdomain constraint (since rack uses this header for the `host_with_port` method as shown [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack%2FRequest%2FHelpers:host_with_port)).

The solution is to deploy the Kong instance under the API subdomain (for the constraint to apply correctly), and proxy the requests to our rails server as usual.